# Paypal recurring profile, Recurring payment doesn't charge

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am beginner with Paypal Recurring Payment.

I have created a recurring profile on **Sandbox account**. The period was of 4 days.
So the scenario was like, i have created profile on 25th Dec 2014 and the due date for first payment was 30th Dec 2014.

However on due date, paypal didn't charge the recurring amount to the profile.

I came across this issue around 3-4 times. I tried google as well but didn't get the solution.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of issue when I first, started implementing the paypal recurring payment services on my oscommerce based website. It took completely 10-15 days to understand and fix this issue.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166006/paypal-recurring-profile-not-charging-automatically

I would suggest you to check your code and ensure you are sending correct set of parameters while making call to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile as the problem lies here itself.

**If you making initial payment, checkout for correct required params
**If you are charging one time payment and then creating recurring profile, then you need to checkout whole process.

Ref: http://www.makemypost.com/implement-recurring-payment-using-paypal-express-checkout/

At the below of the page you can get complete source code from google for implementing recurring payments.

Thanks

Comment: First link is Deeead deeeeead deeadd.